# How to set up and connect development environment for drupal?

Tags: drupal-7, server, mariadb

We are working on a Drupal based website. At least three people are working on different parts at the same time. Till now all of them worked on the live environment. As things became more complicated, we have to separate development and live environments.
I need to know how to set up development environment and connect it to the live environment? How to apply verified developed changes both in code and database to the live environment?
Thank you.

Comment: This question goes well beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer.  Have you searched online for tutorials or books on this subject?

Comment: I just need guidelines or leads, not detailed or step by step manual. Couldn't find a specific document.

Answer (score 0):

As far as code management, you could look into Git following the standard "[GitFlow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow)". For database changes (settings, not content), use the [Features module](https://www.drupal.org/project/features).